# How to host windows services in unix systems?

Tags: c#, unix, windows-services

Can any one tell me the process of hosting windows services in unix systems?

Comment: You can't, without a VM of some kind.

Comment: hi @MichaelPetrotta can you please explain a little bit more..

Comment: I'm sensing that someone asked you to investigate the possibility of doing this. Am I right? Can you provide more detail on how this requirement arose? Anyway, [here's more information on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), and [here's one popular implementation](http://www.vmware.com/).

Comment: i need to work on that .it's requirement given by client .client having unix system i am a .net developer.then how to host my services in uinx type of systems?it is possible or not?

Comment: as stated above it is not possible. unless you install virtual Windows Machine on Unix.